# r markdown plot always on second page

Tags: r, markdown

I knit a markdown file to word.
I have 3 plots in it. The first plot always places itself on the second page, eventhough I resize it to small.

Below the markdown script in which this occurs

````
---
title: "Melding stats rapportage"
output: word_document
---
Author: PDG  
```{r echo=FALSE, comment=NA}
d<-format(Sys.Date(), "%d-%m-%Y")
dd<- "Date:"
knitr::kable(paste(dd, d))
```
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```
```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```
```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```
````

Comment: Made the script reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to make sure the graphs don't start on the second page.
It seems that if the graph code is put immediatly behind each other than the output is taken by Markdown as one piece instead of 3 single graphs.
Putting a line between the 3 pieces of graph code makes Markdown take the 3 graphs as single and the first graph is putted nicely on the first page.

Correction in the code that does the trick:

````
```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```
````